# listen and Connect on different sockets

Tags: c, sockets

Is it possible to call both listen(scokfd1) and connect(sockfd2) in the same source file on different ports wiht same IP

Much Thanks,
AB

Comment: I don't see a reason why not. Do you have any code that suggests otherwise?

Comment: Yes. Did you even try it? What error did you get? Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In fact, it's very common, when we're testing network applications locally (i.e., using IP address 127.1, localhost).

Answer (score 0):

For each address family (IPv4/IPv6), TCP maintains 64K ports for every host. So, choosing two ports from these, one for listen and one for connect should work just fine. Please note that if you do not issue a bind(sockfd2), then connect(sockfd2) would implicitly allocate a temporary port (from the 64K pool) implicitly. The main thing is that for a TCP, the 4-tuple (src_ip, src_port, dest_ip, dest_port) should be unique.